# Simple question on plot from R's glmnet package

Tags: r, regression, regularization, glmnet

I have a very basic question concerning a glmnet plot, but somehow am not able to explain it to myself.

Currently, I work through the [`glmnet` vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html).

I stumbled upon the following example:

```
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y)
plot(cvfit)
```

[image]

Note that the minimum lambda found is 0.08307. This value should be represented at the x-axis of the plot at the left dotted vertical line.

However, when I calculate, I get $\log(0.08307)= -1.080555$.

This is different to (ca.) -2.5 shown by the plot.

Any ideas why the plot shows other values? What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: I think you'll get more answers if you edit your question and state explicitly that this is about the R package glmnet (https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html), and give a small reproducible example (i.e. a small, self-contained piece of code that produces the problem you describe)

Comment: Thx for the advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In statistics, unless otherwise specified, "log" usually means the natural logarithm. Your mistake was that you calculated the base-10 logarithm instead. The natural log of 0.08307 is about -2.49.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was something pretty basic.